# MATLAB console output

Tags: matlab, console-output

Say I had a variable called "`x`" and `x=5`.

I would like to do:

```
disp('x is equal to ' + x +'.');
```

and have that code print:

x is equal to 5.

This is how I am used to doing things in Java, so their must be a similar way to do this in MATLAB.

Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to use `disp`, you can construct the string to display like so:

```
disp(['x is equal to ',num2str(x),'.'])
```

I personally prefer to use `fprintf`, which would use the following syntax (and gives me some control over formatting of the value of x)

```
fprintf('x is equal to %6.2f.\n',x);
```

You can, of course, also supply `x` as string, and get the same output as `disp` (give or take a few line breaks).

```
fprintf('x is equal to %s\n',num2str(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

printing out a few scalar variables in matlab is a mess (see answer above). having a function like this in your search path helps:

```
function echo(varargin)
str = '';
for k=1:length(varargin)
    str = [str ' ' num2str(varargin{k})];
end 
disp(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

just nest a sprintf() inside the disp().

```
    disp(sprintf("X is equal to %d.",x));
```